# How to call an API with the response from another API using RxSwift and Alamofire library?

Tags: swift, alamofire, rx-swift

How to call an API with the response from another API  using RxSwift and Alamofire library? In order to get a final result array. Can anyone suggest me one example..

Answer (score 0):

You would use the `flatMapLatest` operator.

```
firstRequestObservable()
.debug("first request result")
.flatMapLatest { result in
    self.secondRequestObservable(with: result) 
}
.debug("second request result")
```

Every time, `firstRequestObservable` emits a `next` event, previous (if any) `secondRequestObservable` will be overwritten with a new request.

You can use `RxAlamofire` or wrap an alamofire request into an observable.
My knowledge of Alamofire is limited but here is a basic example without handling the possibility of cancelling the request:

```
Observable<YourReturnType>.create { observable in
    Alamofire.request("https://my.api/request").responseJSON { response in
        if let json = response.result.value {
            // you would typically map this json to a relevant model, using Codable perhaps
            observable.onNext(json)
        }

        observable.onCompleted()
    }
    return Disposables.create { /* some code that can cancel the request */ }
}
```